$E_k$-operads and actions on objects inside $k$-tuply monoidal $n$-category
I understood more or less the claim that $k$-tuply monoidal $n$-categories can be seen as $n$-categories equipped with an action of the $E_k$-operad.
For $k=2$, we have a homotopy equivalence $E_2(r) \cong K(P_r, 1)$, where $P_r$ is the pure braid group on $r$ strands. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a braided monoidal category, so $E_2$ acts on $\mathcal{C}$. Moreover, we have an action of $P_r$ on objects of the form $V_1 \otimes \dots \otimes V_r \in \mathcal{C}$.
My question is, is there some higher analogue to $P_r$ for $k>2$?

Edit: the answer is basically given in the comments of this question: Braid 2-groups, symmetric 2-groups
However, I would be very happy about a definitive answer in terms of generators and relations of this 2-group. As far as I understood, it should involve the Zamolodchikov Tetrahedron equation.

Edit: I just noticed that I'm actually also interested in $n > 1$ (not just higher $k$), which my previous Edit refers to.

Yes. This is worked out in my paper with Michael Batanin "Homotopy theory of algebras of substitudes and their localisation". Search for "higher braided operad" in that paper. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2022-375-05/S0002-9947-2022-08600-1/home.html

Thx, I'll have a look!

Could you maybe be a bit more specific, where the desired objects come up in your paper and how?

You can email me.
